# How to access database using JpaRepository without springboot

Tags: database, spring-boot, jparepository

I have a website that uses JpaRepository with @Autowired ok, it is possible to access databases using springboot stuff.

But I have another application that do mining on this database.

Is it possible to access the database using existing JpaRepository, but in a java default program outside of springboot?

e.g. I want do access the dabases like this:

```
public interface MyJPARepository extends JpaRepository<Dashboard, Integer> {
}

public class EntryPointMining {
    @Autowired
    private MyJPARepository myRepository;

    void testData() {
        long count = myRepository.count();
        System.out.println("-- cout: " + count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EntryPointMining().testData();
    }
}
```

But obviously myRepository in this example is null because it doesnt start things correclty.

I'm wondering if it is possible to acess the dabases using existing JpaRepositories because it will make the process of mining much easier.